# WPF slow performance when using too many custom controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF programming and I have a problem with slow performance in my application.

I have a view with grid and 2 columns. First columns is ListBox where are RunTypes and second column is detail view of the RunType. In this detail view, there are some basic controls for properties like Label, etc. and a NavBar control (from devexpress) where are RunConfigs. The NavBar works like an accordion control that shows all RunConfigs and their detail can be expanded.

I needed an option for controlling visibility and enabled state of all fields, so I created this custom control:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ManualDistill.Controls"
                    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:ManualDistill.Converters">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:EditorControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsInEditMode" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=EditContent}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsInEditMode" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ViewContent}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

and cs file:

```
public class EditorControl: ContentControl
{

    public EditorControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(EditorControl);
        //DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(EditorControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(EditorControl)));

        Messenger.Default.Register<LayoutChangeMessage>(this,
        (message) =>
        {
            if (this.Feature == message.Feature && this.DisplayField == message.DisplayField)
            {
                if (message.LayoutData != null)
                {                        
                    DispatcherHelper.RunAsync(() =>
                    {
                        ResetLayout();
                        SetLayout(message.LayoutData);
                    });
                }
            }                
        });
    }

    #region DependencyProperties
    /// <summary>
    /// If the control is currently in edit mode
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsInEditMode
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsInEditModeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsInEditModeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsInEditModeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsInEditMode",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(EditorControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public string DisplayField
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayFieldProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisplayFieldProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayFieldProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayField",
       typeof(string),
       typeof(EditorControl),
       new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string Feature
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FeatureProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FeatureProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FeatureProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("Feature",
       typeof(string),
       typeof(EditorControl),
       new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public object EditContent
    {
        get { return GetValue(EditContentProperty); }
        set
        {                
            SetValue(EditContentProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EditContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("EditContent",
                    typeof(object),
                    typeof(EditorControl),
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((object)null));

    public object ViewContent
    {
        get { return GetValue(ViewContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ViewContent",
                    typeof(object),
                    typeof(EditorControl),
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((object)null));
    #endregion

    public Visibility DefaultVisibility { get; set; }
    public bool DefaultIsEnabled { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);

        this.DefaultVisibility = this.Visibility;
        this.DefaultIsEnabled = this.IsEnabled;

        if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            var layouts = StillLayoutManager.Instance.GetActiveLayouts(this.Feature, this.DisplayField);
            if (layouts != null)
            {
                SetLayout(layouts);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ResetLayout()
    {
        this.Visibility = this.DefaultVisibility;
        this.IsEnabled = this.DefaultIsEnabled;
    }

    private void SetLayout(IEnumerable<ILayoutData> layouts)
    {
        foreach (var data in layouts)
        {
            this.Visibility = data.Visibility ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            this.IsEnabled = data.Editable;                
        }            
    }
}
```

So as you can see I have 2 content properties for edit/view and set them on Content property based on the edit mode. This custom control works then like a container for every field or every object I need. The field or object visibility can be then managed by a system which manipulates these controls (this is not related to the question it is just an explanation why I have these controls there)

The problem is, when I click on the listbox with RunType, I have to wait a couple of seconds until I see the detail. All the controls are created and then disposed so nothing is remembered. The RunType collection will be changed so there could be added more or removed from. So the controls are always created dynamically.

The xaml files for the RunManagement, RunTypeControl and RunConfigControl are here:

```
<UserControl ...> 
      <Grid cmn:GridUtils.ColumnDefinitions="Auto, *">
                <lc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical" View="GroupBox" Header="{lex:LocTextUpper RunType}" MinWidth="250">
                    <dxe:ListBoxEdit x:Name="RunTypesList" 
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding RunTypes}"
                                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRunType}">
                        <dxe:ListBoxEdit.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="{lex:LocText Copy}" Command="{Binding CmdCopy}"/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </dxe:ListBoxEdit.ContextMenu>
                        <dxe:ListBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Label}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </dxe:ListBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
                    </dxe:ListBoxEdit>
                </lc:LayoutGroup>

                <Grid Grid.Column="1">                        
                    <local:RunTypeControl DataContext="{Binding SelectedRunType}" />
                </Grid>
        </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

...

```
<UserControl ...>        
    <Grid  Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <lc:LayoutControl Orientation="Horizontal">
            <lc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical">  
                <controls:EditorControl IsInEditMode="{Binding IsInEditMode}">
                    <controls:EditorControl.ViewContent>
                        <lc:LayoutItem Label="{lex:LocText Label}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" />
                        </lc:LayoutItem>
                    </controls:EditorControl.ViewContent>
                    <controls:EditorControl.EditContent>
                        <lc:LayoutItem Label="{lex:LocText Label}">
                            <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding Label}"/>
                        </lc:LayoutItem>
                    </controls:EditorControl.EditContent>
                </controls:EditorControl>                        
            </lc:LayoutGroup>
            <lc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical">
                <lc:LayoutItem>
                </lc:LayoutItem>
            </lc:LayoutGroup>
        </lc:LayoutControl>

        <lc:LayoutGroup Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5" View="Tabs">
            <lc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Horizontal" Header="{Binding TabHeaderRunStates}">
                <lc:LayoutItem>
                        <dxn:NavBarControl Name="navBar" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding RunConfigs}" Margin="10 0 0 0">
                            <dxn:NavBarControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <controls:EditorControl IsInEditMode="{Binding IsInEditMode}">
                                        <controls:EditorControl.ViewContent>
                                            <dxn:NavBarGroup DisplaySource="Content" Header="{Binding DisplayName}" IsExpanded="False">
                                                <dxn:NavBarGroup.Content>
                                                    <local:RunConfigControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>                                                       
                                                </dxn:NavBarGroup.Content>
                                            </dxn:NavBarGroup>
                                        </controls:EditorControl.ViewContent>
                                        <controls:EditorControl.EditContent>
                                            <dxn:NavBarGroup DisplaySource="Content" Header="{Binding DisplayName}" IsExpanded="False">
                                                <dxn:NavBarGroup.Content>
                                                    <local:RunConfigControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>
                                                </dxn:NavBarGroup.Content>
                                            </dxn:NavBarGroup>
                                        </controls:EditorControl.EditContent>
                                    </controls:EditorControl>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dxn:NavBarControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <dxn:NavBarControl.View>
                                <dxn:ExplorerBarView Click="ExplorerBarView_Click"
                                                     GroupAdding="ExplorerBarView_GroupAdding" />
                            </dxn:NavBarControl.View>
                        </dxn:NavBarControl> 
                </lc:LayoutItem>
            </lc:LayoutGroup>
        </lc:LayoutGroup>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

...

```
<UserControl ...>
    <AdornerDecorator>
        <lc:LayoutControl Orientation="Horizontal">
            <lc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical"> 

                <controls:EditorControl IsInEditMode="{Binding IsInEditMode}">
                    <controls:EditorControl.ViewContent>
                        <lc:LayoutItem Label="{lex:LocText CloseCut}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CloseCut}" />
                        </lc:LayoutItem>
                    </controls:EditorControl.ViewContent>
                    <controls:EditorControl.EditContent>
                        <lc:LayoutItem Label="{lex:LocText CloseCut}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
                            <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding CloseCut}" Width="200"/>
                        </lc:LayoutItem>
                    </controls:EditorControl.EditContent>
                </controls:EditorControl>

                <controls:EditorControl IsInEditMode="{Binding IsInEditMode}">
                    <controls:EditorControl.ViewContent>
                        <lc:LayoutItem Label="{lex:LocText PressureSetpoint}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PressureSetpoint}"/>
                        </lc:LayoutItem>
                    </controls:EditorControl.ViewContent>
                    <controls:EditorControl.EditContent>
                        <lc:LayoutItem Label="{lex:LocText PressureSetpoint}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
                            <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding PressureSetpoint}" Width="200"/>
                        </lc:LayoutItem>
                    </controls:EditorControl.EditContent>
                </controls:EditorControl>

                <controls:EditorControl IsInEditMode="{Binding IsInEditMode}">
                    <controls:EditorControl.ViewContent>
                        <lc:LayoutItem Label="{lex:LocText SpinningBand}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SpinningBand, Converter={StaticResource BooleanOnOffConverter}}" Width="200" />
                        </lc:LayoutItem>
                    </controls:EditorControl.ViewContent>
                    <controls:EditorControl.EditContent>
                        <lc:LayoutItem Label="{lex:LocText SpinningBand}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
                            <dxe:ToggleSwitchEdit IsChecked="{Binding SpinningBand}" IsEnabled="True" ContentPlacement="Both"
                                                  CheckedStateContent="{lex:LocText ON}" 
                                                  UncheckedStateContent="{lex:LocText OFF}"/>
                        </lc:LayoutItem>
                    </controls:EditorControl.EditContent>
                </controls:EditorControl>

                ...

            </lc:LayoutGroup>
        </lc:LayoutControl>
    </AdornerDecorator>
</UserControl>
```

I know there is too much xaml code I tried to make it shorter and show just the important parts.

If I do not use the custom controls and have just 2 listboxes for selecting runtype and runconfigs and view details, then it is working fast.

I counted the number of controls created during the process. If a runtype has 4 properties and 5 runconfigs and each runconfig has 8 properties, then I create 88 custom controls:

8 custom controls => 4 properties (4 for edit mode and 4 for view mode)
80 custom controls => 5 x 8 runconfig properties (40 controls for edit mode and 40 for view mode)

This is the problem that slows down the performance, but i thought WPF can do this without a problem for even bigger number of controls. Am I doing something wrong, do I need to set up some setting on the controls?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: put the `IsInEditMode` `DependencyProperty` to the `UserControl` level, it might boost the performance

Comment: @kurakura88 Hi, your suggestion solves the problem with creating controls for both edit and view mode (which cannot be both active). But it does not solve the problem of performance. Yes, now I just do not need 80 controls but 40, still it is not smooth when I click on the listbox and change selection. If I ever need more properties in view model, I will end up with 50-60 controls anyway and it will be slow.